# How can i write java reverse string program in ACM Library

Tags: java, string, eclipse, reverse, acm-java-libraries

I need a java program which reverse a string with using methods.

For example,

input:-"hellojava"

output:- "avajolleh"

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` it has a reverse method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use

```
String word= "hellojava";

new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString();
```

for one word you need below one.

```
String word= "hello java";

for (String part : word.split(" ")) {
    System.out.print(new StringBuilder(part).reverse().toString());
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

This is supported since java 1.5 ealier versions you should use StringBuffer. And for any Java based project you can use this method.

```
new StringBuffer (word).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the next:

```
String output = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
```